# Deleting from Firestore

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angular-material, angular8

I am implementing admin dashboard system for system admin, and I am using Angular Material and Angular 8. Add the users and viewing in the table part is working fine. but I like to input the part that when I click the delete button it should be deleted. but it's not working,

Here my

system-user.component.html

```
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addNew">Add New System User</button>
      </div>

  </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
        </mat-form-field>

        <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
          <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

            <!-- ID Column
            <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </td>
            </ng-container> -->

            <!-- Full Name Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="fullName">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Full Name </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.fullName}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- User Name Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="username">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> User Name </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.username}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- Role Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="role">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Role </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.role}} </td>
            </ng-container>

             <!-- NIC Column -->
             <ng-container matColumnDef="nic">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> NIC </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.nic}} </td>
            </ng-container>

             <!-- Telephone -->
             <ng-container matColumnDef="telNo">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Contact Number </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.telNo}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Click to Edit" class="iconbutton" color="primary" (click)="deleteSystemUsers($event, row)" >
                  <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                  </button>
                <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Click to Delete" class="iconbutton" color="warn">
                  <i class="material-icons">close</i>
                  </button>
              </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
            </tr>
          </table>

          <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
        </div>

      </div>


    </div>


  </div>
</div>

<!-- Buy-Modal-angular -->
<div class="modal modal-angular fade" id="addNew" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body text-center">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <!-- form to add System Users-->
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header card-header-danger">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Add New System User</h4>
                    <!-- <p class="card-category">Complete your profile</p> -->
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">

                    <form class="create-form"  [formGroup]="sysUsersForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(sysUsersForm.value)">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">

                              <div class="form-group">
                                <!-- <input matInput type="hidden" formControlName="id" class="form-control"> -->
                                <mat-form-field class="input-style">
                                  <input matInput placeholder="User Name" class="form-control" formControlName="username">

                                </mat-form-field>
                                <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.username">
                                  <mat-error *ngIf="sysUsersForm.get('username').hasError(validation.type) && (sysUsersForm.get('username').dirty || sysUsersForm.get('username').touched)">{{validation}}</mat-error>
                                </ng-container>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <mat-form-field class="input-style">
                                  <input matInput placeholder="User Name" class="form-control" formControlName="fullName">
                                </mat-form-field>
                                <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.username">
                                  <mat-error *ngIf="sysUsersForm.get('fullName').hasError(validation.type) && (sysUsersForm.get('fullName').dirty || sysUsersForm.get('fullName').touched)">{{validation}}</mat-error>
                                </ng-container>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="row">

                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <mat-form-field class="input-style">
                                <input matInput placeholder="NIC" class="form-control" formControlName="nic">
                              </mat-form-field>
                              <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.username">
                                <mat-error *ngIf="sysUsersForm.get('nic').hasError(validation.type) && (sysUsersForm.get('nic').dirty || sysUsersForm.get('nic').touched)">{{validation}}</mat-error>
                              </ng-container>

                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <mat-form-field class="input-style">
                                <input matInput placeholder="Contact Number" class="form-control" formControlName="telNo">
                              </mat-form-field>
                              <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.username">
                                <mat-error *ngIf="sysUsersForm.get('telNo').hasError(validation.type) && (sysUsersForm.get('telNo').dirty || sysUsersForm.get('telNo').touched)">{{validation}}</mat-error>
                              </ng-container>

                            </div>
                          </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">


                              <mat-form-field class="input-style">
                                <mat-label>User Role</mat-label>
                                <select matNativeControl placeholder="User Role" class="form-control" formControlName="role">
                                  <option value="0">System Admin</option>
                                  <option value="1">Editor</option>
                                  <option value="2">Hospital Admin</option>
                                  <option value="3">Admin</option>
                                </select>
                              </mat-form-field>
                              <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.role">
                                <mat-error *ngIf="sysUsersForm.get('role').hasError(validation.type) && (sysUsersForm.get('role').dirty || sysUsersForm.get('role').touched)">{{validation}}</mat-error>
                              </ng-container>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <mat-form-field class="input-style">
                                <input matInput placeholder="Password" type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password">
                              </mat-form-field>
                              <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.password">
                                <mat-error *ngIf="sysUsersForm.get('password').hasError(validation.type) && (sysUsersForm.get('password').dirty || sysUsersForm.get('password').touched)">{{validation}}</mat-error>
                              </ng-container>

                            </div>
                          </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="submit-button-container">
                          <button mat-raised-button type="submit" class="submit-button pull-right" color="primary" [disabled]="sysUsersForm.invalid">Add the User</button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

And here my system.users.service.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { SystemUsers } from '../shared/system-users.model';
import { Scheduler, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SystemUsersService {
  dataSource: SystemUsers;
  systemUsers: Observable<SystemUsers[]>;
  systemUsersCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<SystemUsers>;
  systemUsersList: AngularFirestoreDocument<SystemUsers>;

  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {
    this.systemUsersCollection = this.firestore.collection('System Users');

    this.systemUsers = this.systemUsersCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes=>{
      return changes.map(a=>{
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as SystemUsers;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      })
    }))
   }


  createSystemUser(value){
    return this.firestore.collection('System Users').add({
      username: value.username,
      fullName: value.fullName,
      nic: value.nic,
      telNo: value.telNo,
      role: value.role,
      password: value.password
    })
  }

  deleteSystemUsers(dataSource: SystemUsers){
    this.systemUsersList = this.firestore.doc('systemUsers/${row.id}');
    this.systemUsersList.delete();


  }

}
```

Finally system-users-.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatSort} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FirebaseService } from 'app/services/firebase.service';
import { SystemUsersService } from 'app/services/system-users.service';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';




    export interface UserData{
      // id: number;
      username: string;
      fullName: string;
      nic: string;
      telNo: string;
      role: string;
      password: string;

    }

    export interface Role{
      value: number;
      viewValue: string;
    }


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-system-users',
      templateUrl: './system-users.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./system-users.component.scss']
    })
    export class SystemUsersComponent implements OnInit {
      //Modal Form to inser user
      sysUsersForm: FormGroup;

      //Validation error messages
      validation_messages = {
        'fullName':[
          { type:'required', message: "Please fill this"}
        ],
        'username':[
          { type:'required', message: "Please fill this"}
        ],
        'nic':[
          { type:'required', message: "Please fill this"}
        ],
        'telNo':[
          { type:'required', message: "Please fill this"}
        ],
        'role':[
          { type:'required', message: "Please fill this"}
        ],
        'password':[
          { type:'required', message: "Please fill this"}
        ]
      };

      @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
      @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;

      //systemUserList: AngularFirestoreCollection<UserData>;
      dataSource: MatTableDataSource<UserData>;
      displayedColumns: string[] = ['fullName', 'username', 'role','nic', 'telNo','action'];

      constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        public dialog: MatDialog,
        private router: Router,
        public firebaseService: FirebaseService,
        public systemUsersService: SystemUsersService,
        private firestore: AngularFirestore
      ) { 



      }

      ngAfterViewInit(){
        this.firestore.collection<UserData>('System Users').valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
          this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        })
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        // this.resetFields();
        this.addSystemUser();
      }

      addSystemUser(){
        this.sysUsersForm = this.fb.group({
          fullName: ['', Validators.required],
          username: ['',Validators.required],
          nic: ['',Validators.required],
          role: ['',Validators.required],
          telNo: ['',Validators.required],
          password: ['',Validators.required]
        });

      }



      resetFields(){
        this.sysUsersForm = this.fb.group({
          fullName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          username:  new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          nic:  new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          role:  new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          telNo:  new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          password:  new FormControl('', Validators.required),

        });
      }


      deleteSystemUsers(event,row){
        const response = confirm("Are you sure want to delete?");
        if(response){
          this.systemUsersService.deleteSystemUsers(row);
        }
      }
      showMessage : boolean = false;

      onSubmit(value){
        this.systemUsersService.createSystemUser(value)
        .then(
          res =>{
            this.showMessage = true;
            this.resetFields();

            this.router.navigate(['system-users']);

          }
        )
      }

      applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
        this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

        if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
          this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
        }
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a mismatch at the collections you are writing.

You are creating your documents at `System Users` and removing them at `systemUsers`. `system_users` would be my preferred collection name

Comment: no it is not the issue here, I have changed an tried

Comment: then you should debug and check that row.id is indeed the document you want to delete. you should also separate your delete operation into `this.firestore.collection('systemUsers').doc(row.id)`